# How to add "cold data node" to elasticsearch cluster using helm?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, elastic-stack

I would like to add ***COLD*** data node (***NOT*** data node) to my elasticsearch cluster using helm:

My values.yaml:

```
...
roles:
  master: "false"
  ingest: "false"
  data: "false"
  remote_cluster_client: "false"
  ml: "false"
  data_cold: "true"
...
```

but when deploy it, i got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [node.data_cold] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
```

Any idea please ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more context. like for example: what helm chart are are using? It not enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Elastic helm charts, I accomplished this by setting the following in my `values.yml`:

```yaml
extraEnvs:
  - name: 'node.attr.data'
    value: '{{ ilm_phase }}'
```

and setting the following in my `vars.yml` for each individual data tier:

```yaml
ilm_phase: 'cold'  # ...or hot, or whatever...
```

And then finally, using a custom node attribute in my ILM policy.

It's not ideal, but it works well, even if it's not as nuanced as using `node.roles`. If someone else has a better method, I'm open to it.

## Edit

I forgot that I also added the following template, which applies to all new indices created. This forces all new indices to be created on the hot data nodes.

```json
PUT _template/ilm-set-index-ilm-hot
{
  "order": 127,
  "index_patterns": [ "*" ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "routing": {
        "allocation": {
          "require": {
            "data": "hot"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {},
  "aliases": {}
}
```